# bxSlider Left/Right Arrows stop working when 3 slides are dynamically added

Tags: javascript, jquery

thanks everyone for taking time to look into this issue.

So the page I'm working on has:-

1) SHOPPING CART implemented in bxSlider, so basically it's a list of products user has added and user can slide through all the products and each product has a CROSS button so user can remove it.

2) PRODUCT LIST, this is basically a list of related products and each product has a PLUS button so user can add it to the Shopping Cart.

Users can add products to the Shopping Cart in two ways, either by clicking the Plus button or by dragging the product and dropping it in the Shopping Cart, for the drag and drop functionality I am using Kendo UI Framework, I can drag and drop as many products to the shopping cart and bxSlider works perfectly but if I add more than 2 products via the PLUS button then the Left/Right arrows in bxSlider stop working.

Update:-
I noticed that when I add a new product to the Shopping Cart, the previous product I added gets hidden via the display: none; property.

Here's the JavaScript code:-

```
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    minSlides: 2,
    maxSlides: 2,
    slideWidth: 250,
    slideMargin: 0,
    infiniteLoop: false,
    pager: false
});

$('ul.product-list.all-related-list').on('click', 'a.icon-plus', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').toggle('slow', function() {
        $(this).find('.icon-plus').removeClass('icon-plus').addClass('icon-cross');
       $(this).detach().insertBefore('ul.product-list.all-added-list li:first-child').toggle('slow');
        slider.reloadSlider();
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: I hate to presume you overlooked this, but maybe your problem has something to do with `maxSlides: 2,`

Comment: @Timothy, the max slides is not the problem, even removing/modifying it doesn't help.

Comment: @Raj, follow this tutorial http://bxslider.com/examples/reload-slider

Answer (score 1):

As I updated in my post, the code was removing previously added items, following code implements display: block; property on list elements which fixes the bxslider issue.

```
$('ul.product-list.all-related-list li a.icon-plus').one('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').toggle('slow', function() {
        $(this).find('.icon-plus').removeClass('icon-plus').addClass('icon-cross');
       $(this).detach().insertBefore('ul.product-list.all-added-list li:first-child').toggle('slow');
        slider.reloadSlider();
        $(this).siblings().css({'display':'block'});
    });
});
```